# Passwordstrength button validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm using passwordstrength to check my password and it works, but now I want that if I press the register button it only stores the password if it passes the minimal requirements.

This is my code:

```
<ajaxtoolkit:PasswordStrength ID="pwdStrength" TargetControlID="Password" StrengthIndicatorType="Text" PrefixText="Strength:" HelpStatusLabelID="lblhelp" PreferredPasswordLength="8"
                MinimumNumericCharacters="1" MinimumSymbolCharacters="1" TextStrengthDescriptions="Very Poor;Weak;Average;Good;Excellent" TextStrengthDescriptionStyles="VeryPoorStrength;WeakStrength;
                AverageStrength;GoodStrength;ExcellentStrength" runat="server" />
```

Is there a way for the button_click to check if everything is correct? (minimum characters, passwordlength...)

Comment: Not seeing any button_click in your code.  What have you tried?

Comment: I have it after that, I just want to know what i can use in the code behind, like pwdStrength.Something in order to check if it is correct.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm no fan of the AJAX Control Toolkit. I'm also no fan of convoluted password requirements. Require a [twelve character minimum length](https://blog.codinghorror.com/your-password-is-too-damn-short/) and be done with it. [The first answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719700/is-there-any-property-of-password-strength-control-of-ajax-toolkit-that-returns) may inspire you.